# Where can I ask a question about VPN design?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, off-topic

I have the following question about VPN design:

> **Are there VPNs implemented to use several connections instead of just one?**

Some sites I have already tried:

- Stack Overflow: closed as off-topic
- Network Engineering: closed as off-topic

Other sites I considered:

- Information Security: probably off-topic
- Server Fault: probably off-topic
- Super User: probably off-topic

Is there some other site that would be a better fit?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to ask exactly? Are you looking for a VPN client that has a fallback to a second VPN server, a client that connects to multiple servers and directs specific traffic to specific servers, or a nested (TOR-like) VPN client? Depending on what you want, [softwarerecs.se] may or may not be a good fit

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some other site that would be a better fit?

Probably not.  You're asking about a hypothetical implementation, not a concrete implementation.  The Stack Exchange network works best when you have something concrete to ask about rather than something of a "what-if" style.

Comment: @moriarty:  Are you solving a real problem or aren't you?  The network roots itself in professional answers to practical questions, and while each site does have a bit of play in it with their take on that, you've *already* been turned away on most sites that people would think that your question would fit for not being practical enough, and you're reading that the other sites probably wouldn't think that your question is a practical question either.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question to the Software Engineering Stack Exchange and got an answer, though commenters there agreed with me that Network Engineering seems like a better fit.

Also, this time I made up a situation where the "hypothetical implementation" in my actual question would be required, and pretended like that was the problem I was trying to solve. So it seems that theoretical questions are fine, as long as you ask them in a practical context.

Comment: As a sidenote, to a new user the default responses (especially from power users) on the network feel unnecessarily negative. I mean, I'm not posting marketing spam, or a gibberish question or something written in an offensive manner. I'm asking a pretty clear yes/no question about a programming topic I'm not an expert in. Yet I'm told to leave the network because the question is too theoretical?

Comment: I'm curious.  Did you interpret my question as saying that **you** specifically needed to leave the network?  That wasn't what I said, I was simply saying that your hypothetical question wasn't a fit on the network.  It seems that you've adapted my advice to turn your question into a practical one in which you could get a concrete answer for, so that's a win-win for everyone here.  There's no need to respond to negatively, IMO.  Don't extrapolate meaning from the advice given beyond what is said as plainly as possible.

Comment: @Makoto I thought your response together with the previous feedback of multiple curt off-topic closures sent a pretty clear message: "this isn't the place to get your question answered". Maybe you meant "if you rewrite your question people here will answer it" but that isn't the message that got through.

Comment: Nope, that's still you interpolating what was said.  You asked if there was a site that your question fit on, and I said that there probably wasn't, likely due to the fact that it was hypothetical.  You took that and rewrote it to make it into a practical question, which satisfies the network's need to avoid subjective discussion and you made it into a question which works here.  **That's all that transpired.**  Anything other than that was [a story you told yourself](https://cruciallearning.com/blog/crucial-conversations-skill-summary-master-my-stories/) about how we received your question.

Comment: @Makoto I don't see the point arguing about the semantics of what you said. Human communication is grounded in context and tone, and part of being a good communicator is understanding how your literal message may be received differently than intended.

You can dismiss my feedback as "storytelling", but that doesn't change the fact that message I received is clearly different from the one you intended. I added it as a comment because I don't think this experience is unique to me and may be a useful data point for people interested in communicating better with new users.

Comment: The reason I remain engaged is that it's definitely not unique to you, and I've been mindful of what I've been saying to contributors for a very long time.  The challenge before veterans of the community is that they are declared to be rude or gruff, but in practice what I'm showing is that...well, that's really not what happened.  I can't change how you *feel* about the words I said, but I can tell you exactly what I did and did not say, and that's all I believe I've done here.  I haven't *dismissed* your feedback, I'm just saying explicitly that you're interpolating what actually was said.